# How to access Jaeger UI outside localhost. Currently its running as a docker container on a linux machine. No Kubernetes involved

Tags: jaeger

I deployed a jaeger container using `docker run -d -p 6831:6831/udp -p 16686:16686 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest` on a SLES linux. but how do i access it from a remote browser.

The linux ip is pingable but http://linuxip:16686 does not work.

I am not using kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't curl it on "curl -v http://localhost:16686" from the host machine then it is an issue with the container check you're ports are mapped correctly

https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.53/getting-started/

if you can curl it on the host machine but not access it from a browser on another computer within the network then it's a network issue, check no firewalls are blocking the ports both on the linux host and the computer you're trying to access from (windows and company antivirus/firewall software likes to do this)

If you can to both those things and it's an external network you're trying do access it from then remember to setup port forwarding on the router/gateway

any other possible issue you'll need to post some logs before anyone here can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response, curl -v http://localhost:16686 works fine. and ping to the linux ip works fine and also other application running on that box are accessible from remote browser. Is there any configuration needed to access jaeger from remote browser?

Comment: only other suggestion I got is that all the ports listed in the getting started guide will need to be allowed by any third party firewall software and windows defender if you're accessing on windows, windows also doesnt like ephemeral ports so maybe also check thers no port switching going on. And maybe check the router / gateway if you're in an office there might be some rules there.